# Packaging tag missing in pom file

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to follow the spring tutorials from the book Spring In Action 5th edition from Manning publications.
The IDE I am using is Spring Tool Suite 4 and the latest version of Spring Boot I can see from it is 2.2.0

In the example of the pom file given in the book, it's mentioned that there will be a 
`<packaging>jar</packaging>`entry, however in the generated pom file, I don't find it. The book is based on 
version 2.0.4 and the section in the book for the said entry is this:

```
<groupId>sia</groupId>
 <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>taco-cloud</name>
 <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>
```

In the pom file generated in the IDE I see this:

```
<groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Taco Cloud Example</description>
```

Does anyone have any idea why the entry `<packaging>jar</packaging>` is missing?

Comment: by default is not longer necessary to add `packaging` tag since the type is defined by itself, however if you need to specif not for a `jar` packaging like `war` you need to specif it.

Comment: It becomes less relevant when you use the spring-boot-maven-plugin. As an executable jar, spring-boot services become easy to daemonize. I also add in a maven-resources-plugin to do environment variable substitution, in properties, on build, and the git-commit-id-plugin to drop in real commit IDs for the actuators used by spring-admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When no packaging is declared, Maven assumes the packaging is the
>   default: jar

See: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html Section *packaging*.

Java application will packaged to `JAR`, it is default manner.

Answer (score 1):

"jar" is the default packaging type. The value will default to jar if not specified.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan Steutzer